# Postal delivery robot using ubergraph clojure

Tags: recursion, graph, clojure, shortest-path

I am currently working on a route planning robot that will deliver parcels around an office. The office is set up as a graph with weighted edges using ubegraph.

I have a recursive function that can plan the route for a journey between any amount of rooms. However I'm now trying to add 'parcels' to the robot and I'm unsure if the way I'm going about it is correct.

```
(defn journey [start end]
  (alg/pprint-path (alg/shortest-path all-edges {:start-node start, :end-node end, :cost-attr :weight})))

   (defn fullpath [& stops]
  (doall (map (fn [a b] (journey a b)) stops (rest stops) )))
```

Above is the recursive function that at the moment takes in a set of stops and then rights out the route using journey. My idea is that instead of stops I pass in the robot to full path and robot will contain parcels and stops.

```
;;passed into fullpath to plan journey of robot
(def robot [parcels ;;needs to contain a set of parcels
            stops]) ;;stops are all of the end's gathered from parcel
```

The parcels will come from another structure.

```
    ;;passed into robot
(def parcel [start
             end
             delivered])
```

Is this a viable way of doing it or will it be impossible?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Better suited to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Can you tell us what seems doubtful to you? After a quick look, to me it all seems very reasonable. I could have missed something, of course, because I don't know what to look for.